# Blazor Code-Behind: Why Is OnInitialized Not Finding Its Overridden Method?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I am using .NET 6.0.100-preview.6.21355.2 in Visual Studio 2022. I started with the WebAssembly templates, then followed [this YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EhN8DKwSpiQ) for implementing SQL via HTTP API under WebAssembly. The tutorial has a GitHub page with [its code](https://github.com/danpdc/BasicCrudBlazor).

All of that was working fine, and then I decided to move the code out of the Razor pages and into code-behind pages. The first page (counter.razor / counter.razor.cs) worked fine, but the second page is giving me problems. Specifically, I am getting a `no suitable method found to override` error in Intellisense for OnInitialized.

OnInitialized has an empty signature, just as it did when it was on CreateForecast.razor and as it does in [this Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-5.0#component-initialization-oninitializedasync-1). So why the error? Oddly, I receive the same error if I return the code into the base Razor page. There are a few other Intellisense errors, but I suspect including those would be asking more than one question at a time :-).

I've also tried looking up the OnInitialized signature to ensure there isn't something weird going on there. It is listed in ComponentBase as protected void virtual, with no parameters. So, I would expect that a protected override void method with no parameters in a descendant class would match that.

Here is CreateForecast.Razor:

```
@page "/createforecast"
@using CART.Shared
@using CART.Client
@inherits CreateForecast

<h3>Create Forecast</h3>

<div class="row">
    <EditForm Model="@Forecast" OnValidSubmit="InsertForecast">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Date: </label>
            <InputDate @bind-Value="Forecast.Date" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Temperature (C): </label>
            <InputNumber @bind-Value="Forecast.TemperatureC" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Summary: </label>
            <InputText @bind-Value="Forecast.Summary" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Create forecast" />
            <NavLink href="fetchData" class="btn btn-info">Back to forecasts</NavLink>
        </div>

    </EditForm>

</div>
```

(CART is the name of the application.)

Here is CreateForecast.Razor.cs:

```
using CART.Shared;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Json;

namespace CART.Client.Pages
{
    public partial class CreateForecast : ComponentBase
    {
        public WeatherForecast Forecast { get; set; }
        public HttpClient httpClient;
        public NavigationManager navigationManager;
        
        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            Forecast.Date = DateTime.Today;
        }        

        public async Task InsertForecast()
        {
            await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/weatherforecast", Forecast);
            navigationManager.NavigateTo("/fetchdata");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should remove the line

```
@inherits CreateForecast
```

I checked, adding @inherits does produce:

> Error CS0115  'FetchData.BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder)': no suitable method found to override...

That was not obvious.

`@inherits` was used in older versions of Blazor when the classes were not yet generated as `partial`.

Now they are `partial` and you are trying to inherit a class from itself.

Side note, in CreateForecast.Razor.cs you can shorten the defintion to

```
//public partial class CreateForecast : ComponentBase
  partial class CreateForecast
```

this reduces clutter and the chance for errors.

Comment: I can do that, and it removes all of the Intellisense errors, but when I rebuild and run the application it chokes on creating a forecast. The application just says "An unhandled error has occurred." Looking to the Developer Console in Chrome, I get a Null Reference Exception. I'm going to add some try-catches to see if I can narrow down where the error is coming from.

Comment: The null reference is an entirely different error.  Not related to this.