Blazor OnInitialized: No suitable methods found to override
I keep getting these red squiqqlies all over my blazor server project. (I keep my code and razor files separate) The project builds find though without any errors.
When I inherit each of these classes from ComponentBase though, the red squigglies go away. I was under the impression we did not need to inherit from ComponentBase for every razor partial class.
Any idea what I am missing?

@MrCakaShaunCurtis: No, the partial class can (and in my opinion should) take their base class from the generated class. Specifying it should be redundant.

@vibhav - post a code sample. You have some other problem. Specify the folders and namespaces.

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/68713093/60761

@HenkHolterman - correct, comment removed.

Every razor component absolutely has to inherit from ComponentBase, see Code-behind example on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/blazor-for-web-forms-developers/components
If you decompile Blazor project dll, template with Counter example, you will see that every razor file iherits from ComponentBase.


Useful comment and upvoted, but. . . bro, check your spelling :)

@Bennyboy1973 oh yes, thank you, I may be stating the obvious, but English is not my native language. I will use ChatGPT in the future :-)
